# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `type` of type `symbol` supplied to `ForwardRef(InputBase2)`, expected `string`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material UI TextField is causing this error.
I have the prop of type set to password like this

```
type="password"
```

It is not working as it is not hiding the field in the browser and causing the error in the console. What is this type "Symbol" anyways

Comment: What the version your using?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! the prop "InputProp" was causing the issue. if it's null, it causes that issue. I was dynamically setting it so it was null at some points